# Exchange Online Patterns in Rules

Tags: exchange-server

I'm trying to match any recipients with the address `hello-546@mydomain.com` or `test-653@mydomain.com` to a new rules in exchange online. The important thing it to match email that ends with a `-` followed by 3 digits. I tried to add the pattern `\S*[-]\d\d\d\@mydomain\.com` but im always getting the error `The patterns you specified contains prohibited leading or trailing regex characters.` Not sure which regex characters, as I know that the `\S` is supported.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so the correct pattern is `[-]\d\d\d\@mydomain\.com$`